# Solve Python linear mathematical optimization problem - vector - easy constraint

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I do not know how to set up and solve the following linear optimization problem in Python. Can you help?

*R* and *Beta* are vectors of length *n* with known constants.

*x* is a vector of length *n* but is unknown - to be optimized.

constraints:

`B * x = 200  cross product (elementwise product then sum)

`x(i)>0`

find optimal values in vector *x* such that we maximize:

`max(R * x)`

It seems to be not a very complicated, but I did not succeed setting up the problem in the scipy library. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is the multiplication `B * x` defined? You say vectors, do you mean mathematical ones? if so, are you talking about the cross product of vector `B` and `x` (which is the one the spits out a number) or maybe something else?

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. Yes , cross product then obtaining one scalar from the the sum of the elementwise multiplication

Comment: You can use the `@` operator then

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a linear programming problem, take a look into the [scipy library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)  to solve that.